# Pyspark : How to join two differents datasets with differents conditions with differents columns?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I will join this two datasets with differents conditions of differents columns to obtain one datasets in Pyspark :

```
The first dataset df1 >>>  
| rc1 | rc2 | rc3 | resp|
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| AB2 | AB1 | AB6 | jean|
| AB4 | AB3 | AB7 |shein|
| AB9 | AB5 | AB8 |patrick| 

The second dataset df2 >>> 
| Key | description |
| --- | ------------|
| AB1 |    Normal   |
| AB4 |    Expand   |
| AB3 |    small    |
| AB6 |    Big      |
| AB8 |    First    |
| AB2 |    Dock     |
| AB7 |    Missing  |
| AB9 |    Package  |
| AB5 |    Wrong    | 

I will obtain in final dataset df join with df1 & df2 >>>
| rc1     | rc2    | rc3     | resp    |
| --------| ------ | ------- | ------- |
| Dock    | Normal | Big     | jean    |
| Expand  | Small  | Missing | shein   |
| Package | Wrong  | First   | Patrick | 
Please, can you kelp how I join df1 & df2 ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below implementation -

```
df = (
       df1.join(df2, df1.rc1 == df2.Key, 'inner').drop("Key","rc1") 
          .withColumnRenamed('description', 'rc1') 
          .join(df2, df1.rc2 == df2.Key, 'inner').drop("Key","rc2") 
          .withColumnRenamed('description', 'rc2') 
          .join(df2, df1.rc3 == df2.Key, 'inner').drop("Key","rc3") 
          .withColumnRenamed('description', 'rc3') 
          .select("rc1","rc2","rc3","resp")
     )

df.show()

+-------+------+-------+-------+
|    rc1|   rc2|    rc3|   resp|
+-------+------+-------+-------+
|   Dock|Normal|    Big|   jean|
|Package| Wrong|  First|patrick|
| Expand| Small|Missing|  shein|
+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code

Define a list of columns where you want to substitute values. Create a stack expression and stack the dataframe. Then `join` it with `df2` to substitute the values based on a common `Key`. Finally, `pivot` the dataframe to reshape it back

```
cols = ['rc1', 'rc2', 'rc3']
expr = f"stack({len(cols)}, %s) as (rc, Key)" % ', '.join(f"'{c}', {c}" for c in cols)
result = (
    df1.selectExpr('resp', expr)
    .join(df2, on='key', how='left')
    .drop('Key')
    .groupBy('resp')
    .pivot('rc')
    .agg(F.first('description'))
)
```

#### Result

```
+-------+-------+------+-------+
|   resp|    rc1|   rc2|    rc3|
+-------+-------+------+-------+
|   jean|   Dock|Normal|    Big|
|patrick|Package| Wrong|  First|
|  shein| Expand| small|Missing|
+-------+-------+------+-------+
```